# VBA – Why save workbooks and worksheets into variables

Tags: excel, vba, declaration

I googled this but couldn't find an answer.
I know it is a good practice to work with copies of existing objects, aka:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

'proceed to work with ws instead of ThisWorksheet
'then at the end of this script rewrite ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) with ws
```

But why is it so?
Why not work with the worksheet in question directly?
I am talking not only about the case when you want to edit the workbook, but also about the case when you just need to read data from a workbook.

Comment: Using variables generally improves readability. Side note: a variable is *not* a copy of an existing object.

Comment: What happens if your macro inserts a new Worksheet at the start of the Workbook?  Hint: `ws` and `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` are no longer the same object...

Comment: reply to Chronocidal: this was an illustration example. In such cases I use wb.Sheets("sheet name").

Comment: And you think that spreading `wb.Sheets("sheet name")` all over the code is a good idea? What if you rename the sheet, or you want to run the code on another sheet? When you assign a sheet to a variable and use this variable in your code, you need to put the name only in one place of your code

Comment: You declare the variable in the code `ws.range("A1:A2").value` to let the code to know which sheet you want to look at (sheet1 and not sheet2 for the range) and to avoid errors such as "`Runtime error 1004`". To declare it as `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")` allows you to easily track which sheet you work with (readability) but also allows you to make it easy to change worksheet name if you later needs to modify code. You only need to change it one time. `wb.Worksheets(1)` _might_ be more useful when you are more interested in the index number/location rather than the name.

Comment: I do agree that using variables compacts your code and makes it more readable. But, if you use the `With` statement, e.g. `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")`, your code will also be shortened and more readable, with out having to "spread" the worksheet variable all over the code. If too many variables are used, poorly named variables are used, or variables are not properly defined, can cause confusion and errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason I do it is so I don't have to type so much. I'd much rather type `wb` or `ws` than `ThisWorkbook` even with autocomplete. But beyond that general laziness, there is a valid reason for using object variables.

In production code, you should avoid repeating any literal values. And by avoid, I mean be aware of it - there are times when it's OK. Don't use `Worksheets(1)` in multiple places in your code because the `1` literal might change and you have to change it in multiple places. And you run the risk of missing one of those place. So you can

```
Dim lSummarySheetIndex as Long
lSummarySheetIndex  = 1
```

and use `Worksheets(lSummarySheetIndex)` everywhere in your code. Then if the position changes, you can update the variable in one place and know you haven't broken anything. Or, more commonly, you could use an object variable and achieve the same thing.

You may have an instance where `Worksheets(1)` is appropriate. If your code must deal with the first worksheet regardless if someone has moved things around, then that's where the "rule" doesn't apply.

Same with names. Take `Workbooks("SalesQ1.xlsm")`. You can make the name a variable and use that or make the workbook an object variable and use that.

Keywords like `ThisWorkbook` or `Sheets(1)` are not much different than variables. They're built in to the object model and they are pointers to objects in memory. So `ThisWorkbook` says go to memory location 15246789 and return what's there. When you use `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` you're telling VBA to store 15246789 in the wb variable and when you refer to that variable, it knows which memory location to go to for that object. There's very little additional cost in using object variables and it's no more indirect than using built-in keywords.